# Left Join to select all record from table1 and single (optional) record of table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my database i have to table with one to many(optional) relationship `1....0,*`

```
Table1:
+--+---------+
|id|   name  |
+--+---------+
| 1|  user1  |
| 2|  user2  |
| 3|  user3  |
+--+---------+
```

```
Table2
+--+------+-------+
|id|tb1_ID|city   |
+--+------+-------+
| 1|   1  |  a    |
| 2|   1  |   b   |
| 3|   2  |   c   |
+--+------+-------+
```

Now here i want all present records from table 1 and Top 1 element of table2(for each table 1 row)

Like

```
+----+------+----+--------+---------+
|p.id|p.name|c.id|c.tb1_ID|c.city   |
+----+------+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | user1|  1 |    1   |    a    |
|  2 | user2|  3 |    2   |    c    |
|  3 | user3|null|   null |   null  |
+----+------+----+--------+---------+
```

HOw???

Comment: What is the link between table1 and table2 - what columns join and how?

Comment: In your example, what rule do you use to pick `'a'` over `'b'` for the `city` to assign to `'user1'`?

Comment: id at table1 is primary key and tb1_ID is foreign key

Answer (score 2):

For example with this [`WITH common_table_expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)  and [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  t1.id AS t1ID
    ,       t1.name 
    ,       t2.id AS t2ID
    ,       t2.tb1_ID
    ,       t2.city
    ,       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By t1.id Order By t2.id)AS t1RowNum
    FROM Table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.tb1_ID
)
SELECT cte.* 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  t1RowNum = 1
```

Comment: +1 : Actually picks one record in T2 per record in T1 *(which other answers here chose to ignore...)*. And does it the way I'd expect to be fastest :)  *[Assuming appropriate indexes.]*

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a subquery with OUTER APPLY to isolate the single row in the right table.

```
select t1.*, t2.* 
from table1 t1 
outer apply
(
    select top 1 *
    from table2
    where tb1_id = t1.id
    order by id
) as t2
```

Comment: +1 : Actually picks one record in T2 per record in T1 *(which other answers here chose to ignore...)*.  But I'd compare and contrast performance with the `ROW_NUMBER() = 1` alternative.

Comment: It's a good idea to order the subquery if a certain row is required.

Comment: @bendataclear - yes it is, but unfortunately the OP left that part out and only specified TOP 1

Comment: Updated answer - changed to OUTER APPLY

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a 1 to many relationship you want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id, c.tb1_ID, c.city
FROM Table1 p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 c
ON p.id = c.tb1_ID
```

If you have a many to many you'll need to decide how you're limiting table 2.

Comment: In the OP's example `User1` relates to two records in Table2 *(cities `'a'` and `'b'`)*, but the OP only wants to return 1 record *(city `'a'`)*. This answer does not address that requirement.

Comment: this will give me all related row from table2